# Maya threading causing crash

Tags: multithreading, maya, pymel

I've started an autosave script editor script (using Maya 2014), but it's really unstable and can crash if something happens at the same time as a save. I also just realised crashes will happen even when not saving, so I tried to find what the actual problem was, and ended up with barely any code left but still able to replicate it.

My idea for the code is to run a background thread, where it'll loop and backup the scripts at an interval, but check a value every second to make sure it's not been paused or cancelled (cancelled will stop the loop).

I presume the problem is something to do with how background threads work in Maya, as it can crash if loading/closing the script editor window, or switching tabs on the render view settings (at least with Mental Ray selected, since it seems to take longer loading tabs than the default renderer). I presume there's other ways, but those are the ones that were really easy to find.

After getting it down to just `time.sleep()` in a while loop, it really doesn't make sense to me as to why it should be causing a crash. I also used a different sleep function that does `while time.time()>startTime+1`, to make sure it wasn't the time module, but it still caused crashes.

Here is the cut down code if anyone wants to try it, once you start the thread with `AutoSave.start()`, if you continuously load and close the script editor window, you should eventually get a runtime error (that says R6025 pure virtual function call). It may take multiple attempts, but it always seems to eventually happen.

```
import threading, time
import pymel.core as pm

class AutoSaveThread(object):
    def __init__( self ):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Open and close the script editor enough times and this will crash"

class AutoSave:
    @classmethod
    def start( self ):
        AutoSaveThread()
```

I have a dozen or so tabs open so loading/closing takes a bit longer than if I had none, this could potentially increase the time window in which crashes can happen.

For the record, here is the bit of code built into Maya that will always run whenever the script editor window is closed. I thought it may have something to do with my modified version of it saving, then this trying to save at the same time, but it's still crashing with nothing happening in the loop.

```
global proc syncExecuterBackupFiles(){
    global string $gCommandExecuter[];
    global string $executerBackupFileName;

    if(`optionVar -q saveActionsScriptEditor`) {
        // clear the script editor temp dir first before writing temp files
        string $scriptEditorTempDir = (`internalVar -userPrefDir` + "scriptEditorTemp/");
        string $tempFiles[] = `getFileList -folder $scriptEditorTempDir`;
        string $file;
        for ($file in $tempFiles) {
            sysFile -delete ($scriptEditorTempDir + $file);
        }

        // save all the executer control text to files
        int $i = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < size($gCommandExecuter); $i++) {
            cmdScrollFieldExecuter -e -storeContents $executerBackupFileName $gCommandExecuter[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping your call to `print` in `pymel.mayautils.executeDeferred` or `maya.utils.executeDeferred` so that it is executed on the main UI thread.

---

> if you continuously load and close the script editor window, you should eventually get a runtime error (that says R6025 pure virtual function call). It may take multiple attempts, but it always seems to eventually happen.

I was able to confirm this behavior on Maya 2012, and I doubt it's version specific.

My bet is that your test call to `print` is what is actually causing Maya to crash, because even though `print` is normally just a python statement, Maya has some sort of hook into it to update the Script Editor's Output Window (and potentially the Command Response bar) with the string you are printing, which are both running on the main UI Thread.

From the [Autodesk Knowledge article "Python and threading"](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/mne-help/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/files/Python-Python-and-threading-htm.html):

> Maya API and Maya Command architectures are not thread-safe. Maya commands throw an exception if they are called outside the main thread, and use of the OpenMaya API from threads other than the main one has unforeseen side effects.

By passing your `print` statement to [pymel.mayautils.executeDeferred](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/PyMel/generated/functions/pymel.mayautils/pymel.mayautils.executeDeferred.html#pymel.mayautils.executeDeferred) I've (at least thus far, who knows with Maya ;-) ) been unable to cause a crash.

```
import threading, time
import pymel.core as pm

import pymel.mayautils  # like maya.utils, for executeDeferred

# Set to False at any time to allow your threads to stop
keep_threads_alive = True

def wrapped_print():
    print "Opening and closing the script editor shouldn't make this crash\n"

class AutoSaveThread(object):
    def __init__(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run)
        thread.start()
    def run(self):
        while keep_threads_alive:
            time.sleep(1)
            pymel.mayautils.executeDeferred(wrapped_print)

...
```

The only side-effect of wrapping specifically a `print` statement is that it no longer echoes to the Command Response bar. If preserving that behavior is important to you just use `pymel.mel.mprint` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much haha, I'd tried wrapping other bits in `executeDeferred` but I didn't think to do it to `print`. The full code will still crash if loading/closing the script editor while it saves (doubt there's much I can do about that but warn people), but so far it seems to work fine otherwise. Just curious, I've always done `maya.utils.executeDeferred` and didn't know about `pymel.mayautils`, is there any advantage of one over the other? Also, is `pymel.mel.mprint` generally better to use than `print` if pymel is loaded?

Comment: @Peter You should be able to make this work without having to worry about crashes, but that depends on how and when you are grabbing data from the script editor.

Comment: @Peter `pymel.mayautils.executeDeferred` is a wrapper for `mel.utils.executeDeferred` that also handles when Maya is run in batch mode, and `print` is a python statement whereas `mprint` makes a call to `maya.mel.eval` to use mel's print. The pymel docs I linked explain the differences on both pretty well, and better yet, the source for both is accessible. See `Python/lib/site-packages/pymel/mayautils.py` and `Python/lib/site-packages/pymel/core/language.py` respectively in your Maya install.

Comment: Ok thanks, and the only way I could get the data from the script editor was through `cmdScrollFieldExecuter( storeContents=True )`, which when commented out, solves all crashes, so I believe it's just that command which is the problem. It's probably because it's also called when the SE window is closed, but nothing I can really do about that unfortunately.

Comment: I've got the script to a working state anyway with a lot less crashes, here it is if you want to try it or see how it saves - https://github.com/Peter92/Maya/blob/master/SEAutoSave.py, go to `def saveScriptEditorFiles`. It's also my first time trying to do proper commenting so some bits might not have been explained in the correct way :)

Comment: @Peter It looks like the only time you are using `executeDeferred` is for print statements, but my point was that you (potentially) need to wrap _any_ call to Maya API or Maya Commands; none of it is thread safe. Your thread and the main thread can potentially call `storeContents` at the same time, but if you execute deferred, your call will be queued until the next idle event. For that reason, you should at least defer your `saveScriptEditorFiles` function when you call it from inside your thread.

Comment: @Peter If you can get away with using `cmdScrollFieldExecuter(storeContents=...)` it's easier than rolling your own, otherwise you can use `cmdScrollFieldExecuter(query=True, text=True)` to get the contents of a field.

Comment: I tried deferring `saveScriptEditorFiles` before I posted the question, so I forgot to do it again after you fixed the print causing crashes. Anyways, it kinda stops the crashes, but also deletes every file if the script editor is closed, which is strange as I put a check in to make sure it'll only delete files if it's going to save. Anyway, thank you so much for the query text idea, so simple and effective and it never crossed my mind to try haha. I'll use that instead of fixing the above problem, it seems a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
import time
import maya.utils as utils
run_timer = True
run_num = 0
def example(interval = 10):
    global run_timer;global run_num;
    def your_function_goes_here():
        print "hello",run_num
        run_num +=1
    while run_timer:
        time.sleep(interval)
        utils.executeDeferred(your_function_goes_here)

t = threading.Thread(None, target = example, args = (1,) )
t.start()

# stop :
# run_timer = False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!